# Integrating Skype for Business 2016 and MS Unified Service Desk (Dynamics 365)

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, unified-service-desk

I am working with MS Dynamics 365 CRM and Unified Service Desk (v2.2.2.815). Our organization uses Skype for Business 2016 (v. 16.0.7726.1049). I have been tasked with integrating SfB and Unified Service Desk. In other words if a Skype incoming call is detected perform X action in USD.

My understanding is the latest version of Skype desktop SDK is **[Lync 2013 SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/skype/skypedeveloperplatform)** (Desktop Components)

Using Lync 2013 SDK, I invoke `LyncClient.GetClient();` and the following error is thrown:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'Microsoft.Office.Uc.UCOfficeIntegration'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{6A222195-F65E-467F-8F77-EB180BD85288}' failed due to the
>   following error: Interface not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040155).

Has anyone successfully integrated SfB 2016 and Microsoft Unified Service Desk by developing a "middleware application" using a Lync/Skype SDK to accomplish that?

[CTI integration between CRM USD and Microsoft Lync](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/mscrmshop/archive/2015/05/11/cti-integration-between-crm-usd-and-microsoft-lync-part-1)

Comment: I never deployed USD, but I'd expect it to "just work" once the integration is setup inside CRM itself

Comment: I was under the same impression because CRM seamlessly integrates with other MS products. My experience so far has been that the "out of the box" CRM -> SfB integration is limited to the outgoing calls (clicking a phone number in CRM and Skype is launched) as well as the status/presence indicator beside a contacts name in CRM/USD. I used the following link if anyone is interested in doing that: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863703.aspx